# How to calculate Poker hand percentages?

Tags: poker-theory, odds

https://www.888poker.com/poker/poker-odds-calculator

Like on the link above, all I get when I google this is how to calculate pot odds. I am not looking for that.

If you go to the link above and add two players, then on only one of the hands you enter 2 aces you get the percentage of 84.6%. I understand this % changes as more cards are on the table but I want to know the process of calculating these percentages mentally, even if its a rough estimate

Comment: As a note:  this percentage assumes that the villain's range is 100% of hands.

Answer (score 0):

After the river is dealt, you either win or lose. The best you can do is "count" how many hands in the villain's range have you beat you and how many don't.

There is no quick way of knowing what your "percentage" is, otherwise poker would be a very easy game and nobody would play it. As a quick rule of thumb, when you have a draw.

After the turn is dealt, estimate your "outs" (number of cards that would complete your hand) and multiply by 2

After the flop is dealt (before the turn), estimate your "outs" and multiply by 4 (this will be slightly off when you have too many outs, but still works OK)

As for preflop hands, with 5 cards to come, calculating on the spot would be too hard, so it's better to just remember some "reference points", then increase it slightly if cards are suited or well connected:

- 90%: AA vs A7........... KK vs K5 and alike
- 80%: QQ vs J7............ 55 vs 32 and alike
- 70%: AJ vs A9............ J9 vs J3 and alike
- 70%: QQ vs K9............ 77 vs Q3 and alike
- 60%: AJ vs K9............ J9 vs 43 (closer to 65-ish) and alike
- 50%: 22 vs 89............. 99 vs AK and alike

Comment: Thank you for your answer! on the link i provided it shows a percentage chance of winning without knowing the opponents hand, also before even the flop. by the time you reach the river chances are some players have already bluffed their hands and pushed other players to flop. as you add the cards from the flop onto the calculator the percentage chance of your hand winning changes. I see you put AA vs A7 is a 90% winning chance although that's assuming you know the opponents hand is A7. on the calculator you need not fill in the opponents hand, just click Add new player to add to the final calc

Comment: pushed other players to fold*

Comment: @Syeeric the problem with those percentage calculators is that they are assuming your opponent has a random hand, which they don't because not every hand is played equally. To make a this list useful, you should average out among all the hands your opponent could have